# How to make css to show a image on mobile but not in desktop

Tags: html, css, web

Hello i am creating a website for fun (I was bored) i am making it responsive using media query in css but i encountered a problem i already have a title in html for desktop and a second title for mobile i want the second title (for mobile) to be show in mobile but not in desktop here is my `home.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Beast Code's</title>
    <style>
    
        ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333333;
    }
    
    li {
      float: left;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #111111;
    }
        
        
        
        </style>
        
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conatiner-1">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">
          <h1>I am CaptainBeast</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="avatar">
      <img src="stuffs/pfp.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-t">
      <h1>Hello i am CaptainBeast</h1>
    </div>
    
   
     
    </div>

</div>
    
</body>



</html>
```

my style.css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro');
    


.conatiner-1{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(stuffs/background.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
.title{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    margin-left: 425px;
    top: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.title {
    border-right: solid 3px rgba(0,255,0,.75);
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;    
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;  
    font-size: 28px;
    color: rgba(90, 145, 207, 0.7);
  }
  
  /* Animation */
.title {
    animation: animated-text 4s steps(29) 1s 1 normal both,
               animated-cursor 600ms steps(29) infinite;
  }
  
  /* text animation */
  
  @keyframes animated-text{
    from{width: 0;}
    to{width: 580px;}
  }
  
  /* cursor animations */
  
  @keyframes animated-cursor{
    from{border-right-color: rgba(0,255,0,.75);}
    to{border-right-color: transparent;}
  }

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px){

  
.avatar img{
  display: none;
}
}


.title-m{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.mobile-t{
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){

.container{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
.conatiner-1{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url(stuffs/background.png);
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
}
.avatar img{
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1000px;
  top: 60;
  image-resolution: from-image;
  
}
.mobile-t{
  font-size: 16px;
}



}
```

Hope i will get a nice answer Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Inside your media query for mobile version add `.mobile-t{display:block}`

Comment: tysm it works nad what should i do for images?

Comment: It's the same thing, use display:none inside the query and it's done. I'll suggest to read [docs about media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: i mean what i should do to make the image to be shown in mobile but not in desktop

Comment: before the media query start you should add img{display:none} and inside the media query add img{display:block}

Answer (score 0):

I've used this on some projects and it actually works for me.
To make a section show on mobile:

```
<div class="mobileShow">
TEXT OR IMAGE FOR MOBILE HERE
</div>
    <style type="text/css">
   .mobileShow { display: none;}
   /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
   @media only screen
   and (min-device-width : 320px)
   and (max-device-width : 480px){ .mobileShow { display: inline;}}
</style>
```

To make a section hide on mobile devices:

```
    <div class="mobileHide">
    TEXT OR IMAGE NOT FOR MOBILE HERE
    </div>
<style type="text/css">
   .mobileHide { display: inline;}
   /* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
   @media only screen
   and (min-device-width : 320px)
   and (max-device-width : 480px){  .mobileHide { display: none;}}
</style>
```